# Does SingleOrDefault() query remotely?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq

Consider an environment with various computers at different locations. These computers have a Windows application running and a timer checking for new data to sync every 5 minutes. Information is synced to a centralised location over an internet connection. The database on both the client computers and the centralised server is an SQL Server database.

Before writing into the remote (centralised) server, the SingleOrDefault() method is used to check whether a record with the same ID exists remotely or not. The client has reported a surge in internet data used. I am wondering whether the centralised database has grown too large and the SingleOrDefault returns the whole queryable data over the connection and does the querying client side. Could this be the case? And what would be an alternate solution that does not do the same thing?

Comment: Since you are querying by primary key, you know there is only one element. Consider using firstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault, as the first one will  query Top 1, while the second one will query Top 2 and check there is no second one. This extra check has no purpose in your case.

Comment: Agreed, there cannot be any duplicates by SQL rule. SingleOrDefault does not query client side but I will fix that nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Queryable.SingleOrDefault` then it will be processed on the server (if you log the database queries you can see the use of `top 2` in the `select`<sup>1</sup>).

However if you are using `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault` then it will be processed on the (database) client.

You need to avoid converting from `IQuerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` (eg. by use of `AsEnumerable`).

Detecting this can be done with code inspection or by looking at the generated SQL.

<sup>1</sup> `top 2` is used to detect more than a single result, which is an error when using `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative and clear answer. This means that the exorbitant amount of internet data must be the cause of something else, as the method is IQuerayble.SingleOrDefault.

Comment: why it would be `top 2` ? isn't it saying `SIngleOrDefault` which means one record is expected back.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad See the footnote! Getting two rows will lead to an exception. `Single` means error if not exactly 1; `SingleOrDefault` means either 0, 1 or error. If you want to allow more than 1 row use `FirstOrDefault`.